# MySQL Limit LEFT JOIN Subquery after joining

Tags: mysql, join, subquery, limit

currently i have this Query:

```
SELECT post.id AS postID, sCom.id as CommentID FROM `post` LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM `comment` LIMIT 5) AS sCom ON sCom.post_id = post.id;
```

Output:

```
postID | CommentID
1      | 1
2      | null
3      | null
4      | 2
5      | 3
5      | 4
5      | 5
```

It works but it LIMITs the comment Table before JOINing. The result is, that it selects the first 5 comments and maps it. All comments over an id of 5 gets ignored.

How can i rewrite the query to have The post with maximum of 5 comments selected ?

The current table structure:

Post :

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `post` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `feed_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `user_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `origin_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `content` longtext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `enabled` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
 `created_at` datetime NOT NULL,
 `updated_at` datetime NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 KEY `IDX_5A8A6C8D51A5BC03` (`feed_id`),
 KEY `IDX_5A8A6C8DA76ED395` (`user_id`),
 KEY `IDX_5A8A6C8D56A273CC` (`origin_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=6 ;
```

Comment:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `comment` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `feed_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `user_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `post_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `content` longtext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `enabled` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
 `created_at` datetime NOT NULL,
 `updated_at` datetime NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 KEY `IDX_9474526C51A5BC03` (`feed_id`),
 KEY `IDX_9474526CA76ED395` (`user_id`),
 KEY `IDX_9474526C4B89032C` (`post_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=11 ;
```

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This will give you 5 comments for every post.

```
SELECT  p.*,
        c.*
FROM    Post p
        LEFT JOIN
        (
            SELECT  a.*
            FROM    Comments a
            WHERE    
                    (
                       SELECT   COUNT(*) 
                       FROM     Comments b
                       WHERE    a.Post_ID = b.Post_ID AND 
                                a.ID <= b.ID
                    ) <= 5
        ) c ON  a.ID = c.Post_ID
```

Comment: @JohnWoo Thanks, this helped me, but I think `a.ID = c.Post_ID` must be `p.ID = c.Post_ID`

Comment: @JohnWoo I feel like you are the guy for [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38581132/left-join-on-like-needs-limit) (please see link), and that your answer should help me, but I just can't figure it out.  I have a `LIKE` making things complicated.