# Load three posts by user

Tags: mysql, select

I am looking to load all posts, sorted by newest first, but also limit them to three per user. I have no idea how to do that though! Here's the SQL I have currently to create the table and select the posts.

```
SELECT p.title, u.firstname, u.lastname
  FROM post p  
  JOIN user u
    ON p.user_id=u.id
 ORDER
    BY u.id, p.ctime DESC
#LIMIT TO 3 by user
;
```

Comment: Did you try: `LIMIT 3`? by the way, the creation of your database is not relevant to the question...

Comment: limit 3 doesn't limit it to three per user. it just limits it to three results period. thanks for participating!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you can do

```
select
u.*,
p.*
from
user u
left join
(
   select  
   p1.*
   FROM    
   post p1
   where    
    (
       select   
       count(*) 
       from
       post p2
       WHERE 
       p1.user_id = p2.user_id
       AND p1.id <= p2.id
    ) <= 3
   order by p1.id desc
) p ON  u.id = p.user_id
order by u.id
```

Took help from [MySQL Limit LEFT JOIN Subquery after joining](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16016719/mysql-limit-left-join-subquery-after-joining)

Comment: you welcome but credit goes to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16016719/mysql-limit-left-join-subquery-after-joining

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might work

```
SELECT u.*,up.* FROM user u LEFT JOIN

(

SELECT `p`.`title`, `u`.`firstname`, `u`.`lastname`
  FROM `post` `p`  
 ORDER
    BY `p`.`ctime` DESC
LIMIT 3 

) 

up on up.user_id = u.id
```

Comment: The query doesn't work but i like where you're going with this. I rewrote it slightly. Howerver, it still doesn't return three rows per user but 3 rows period:
SELECT u.firstname, u.lastname, up.title, up.ctime FROM user u JOIN

(

SELECT `p`.`user_id`, `p`.`title`, `p`.`ctime`
  FROM `post` `p`
 ORDER
    BY `p`.`ctime` DESC
LIMIT 3

) 

up on up.user_id = u.id