# MySQL fetch total 20 rows but only 10 rows of each unique id

Tags: mysql, top-n

I have a little problem here that I'll try to explain. I want to fetch the latest (highest id) maximum 10 rows (can exist more/less than 10) per each unique id in a table.

So if I'm interested in knowing the latest 10 rows from id "1" and "2" I would set the `LIMIT` to 20 (2 * 10).

This is what my current query looks like right now (which incorrectly will fetch latest 20 rows of the first id since it exists more than 10 rows for that id).

```
SELECT positions.id
     , trackedpersons.name
     , trackedpersons.id
     , events.name
     , events.route
     , positions.latitude
     , positions.longitude
     , positions.datetime 
  FROM trackedpersons
     , positions
     , events 
 WHERE trackedpersons.id IN (1,2) 
   AND events.id = 1 
   AND events.id = positions.eventid 
   AND positions.trackedpersonid = trackedpersons.id 
 ORDER 
    BY trackedpersons.id
     , positions.id DESC 
 LIMIT 20;
```

Comment: Do not use implicit (comma-) join syntax. Instead, always use explicit JOIN syntax. Aside from that, this is a Top-N question (of the sort that gets asked and answered here every single day)

Comment: @Strawberry i mostly use implicit joins, what the difference?

Comment: even i too want to know :)

Comment: @Strawberry how much helps your suggestion for Peter?

Comment: MySQL evaluates joins in a different order depending upon whether they're implicit or explicit. If they're all implicit, this won't matter (in the same way that 2*3*6 = 6*2*3), but when combined with OUTER JOINs (which cannot be expressed implicitly), you'll start to get errors or unexpected results. Plus, it's harder to read.

Comment: @flaschenpost It's a comment, not an answer.

Comment: why not use union first query with condition `WHERE trackedpersons.id = 1 ... order by ... limit 10` and then 2nd query `WHERE trackedpersons.id = 2 ... order by ... limit 10`

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty Does that solution scale well?

Comment: no it will not and getting 2 different set of data with condition and then getting subset from both condition is always expensive and I would be interested to know if there is a better solution.

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty, that good solution I'm using since long back, But the problem would be when there are more number of groups that just `two` it would make complicated query, see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12113699/get-top-n-records-for-each-group-of-grouped-results)

Comment: check this out http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/12/07/how-to-select-the-firstleastmax-row-per-group-in-sql/ for selecting the top N rows from each group

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty There is. As I say, this question has been answered many, many times here on SO and elsewhere, so I won't bore you by repeating it here.

Comment: well I gave an answer yesterday but its a different situation where explicit join could be made and then group the data in order http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23501312/load-three-posts-by-user/23501484#23501484 but here there is an explicit condition `WHERE trackedpersons.id IN (1,2) ` and thats the reason I would like to know how it could be optimized.

Comment: I'm using implcit join because this is a dynamic generated query in Java. I can not now beforehand what (and how many) id's to fetch the results for... does that make sense?

Comment: The second part makes sense. The first part does not make sense.

Comment: @Strawberry can you give me a hint how this query can be rewritten, you seem to know the solution...

Answer (score 0):

Very well; here's one way - although it's not the most efficient...

Consider the following...

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table 
(id INT NOT NULL
,dt INT NOT NULL
,PRIMARY KEY(id,dt)
);

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
(101,1),
(101,2),
(101,3),
(101,4),
(102,1),
(102,2),
(102,3),
(102,4),
(102,5),
(103,1),
(103,2),
(103,3),
(104,1),
(104,2),
(105,1);

SELECT * FROM my_table;
+-----+----+
| id  | dt |
+-----+----+
| 101 |  1 |
| 101 |  2 |
| 101 |  3 |
| 101 |  4 |
| 102 |  1 |
| 102 |  2 |
| 102 |  3 |
| 102 |  4 |
| 102 |  5 |
| 103 |  1 |
| 103 |  2 |
| 103 |  3 |
| 104 |  1 |
| 104 |  2 |
| 105 |  1 |
+-----+----+
```

To discover the position (rank) of each row within its group, we can do this...

```
SELECT x.*
     , COUNT(*) rank 
  FROM my_table x 
  JOIN my_table y 
    ON y.id = x.id 
   AND y.dt >= x.dt 
 GROUP 
    BY x.id,x.dt 
 ORDER 
    BY id
     , rank;
+-----+----+------+
| id  | dt | rank |
+-----+----+------+
| 101 |  4 |    1 |
| 101 |  3 |    2 |
| 101 |  2 |    3 |
| 101 |  1 |    4 |
| 102 |  5 |    1 |
| 102 |  4 |    2 |
| 102 |  3 |    3 |
| 102 |  2 |    4 |
| 102 |  1 |    5 |
| 103 |  3 |    1 |
| 103 |  2 |    2 |
| 103 |  1 |    3 |
| 104 |  2 |    1 |
| 104 |  1 |    2 |
| 105 |  1 |    1 |
+-----+----+------+
```

...which can be rewritten thus (obtaining the top 3 from each id)...

```
SELECT x.*  
  FROM my_table x 
  JOIN my_table y  
    ON y.id = x.id 
   AND y.dt >= x.dt 
 GROUP 
    BY x.id
     , x.dt 
HAVING COUNT(*) <= 3;
+-----+----+
| id  | dt |
+-----+----+
| 101 |  2 |
| 101 |  3 |
| 101 |  4 |
| 102 |  3 |
| 102 |  4 |
| 102 |  5 |
| 103 |  1 |
| 103 |  2 |
| 103 |  3 |
| 104 |  1 |
| 104 |  2 |
| 105 |  1 |
+-----+----+
```