# Left Join ON LIKE needs something like LIMIT

Tags: mysql, sql

(**EDIT**:  A trailing `LIMIT` will not solve.  Please read carefully.)

I have a table that looks up text in another table by `LEFT JOIN` and `LIKE` and I would like to limit the amount of results ***per-left-row***.

- Table `usergames AS u` contains substrings of user-inputted strings representing game names.
- Table `games AS g` contains a master list of game names.
- When the user enters a game name like "Hotline Miami", the input is split and 2 entries are created in `substrs`: one containing `"hotline"` & one containing `"miami"` (in the `piece` column), and both containing the full game name (in the `name` column).
- In the event that the full game name does not match anything exactly in the master list, (ex. user mistakenly enters "Haatline Miami"), I check the master list for suggestions, such as any game with `"Haatline"` or `"Miami"`.

This is my query and it is working great:

```
SELECT u.name,g.name AS suggestion,count(g.name)
FROM usergames u
LEFT JOIN games g
ON CONCAT(' ', g.name, ' ') LIKE CONCAT('% ', u.piece, ' %')
GROUP BY g.name, u.name
ORDER BY u.name ASC, count(g.name) DESC
```

The problem I have is that sometimes there are too many suggestions.  Maybe there are 1000 games that have the word "Miami".  How can I limit the many rows created by the join "per left row"?  See the data below, some results are from "hotline" and some from "miami".  How could I limit to X results per substring.

**SAMPLE DATA**

`substrs`

[image]

`games`

[image]

`result`

[image]

<sub>(Note: A trailing `LIMIT` is not what I am looking for, as I don't want to limit the total # of results but only the results-per-joined-item that result from the `LIKE` join)</sub>

<sub>(Note: The `CONCAT` w/ spaces are there to ensure that only full word matches are returned. Mentally remove them if they are confusing, the question would be the same if it was `g.name LIKE s.piece`)</sub>

Comment: For each individual pairing, what's number do you want to limit to?

Comment: Let's say that I'd like to limit to 10.

Comment: Can you add some sample data which clearly shows what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: You may take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16016719/mysql-limit-left-join-subquery-after-joining

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I've added a visual representation of the scenario.  Let me know if anything is unclear.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no expected output.  You asked an unclear question.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I've added the output, which is as expected and desired: essentially a list of possible matches from `g` based on substrings from `s`.  However, I would like to return less results 'per-like' as this result set gets huge when working with many games.  I also edited the query to show exactly what I'm doing.

Comment: Can you give us the sample data as sql?

Comment: See here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/66e8a/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, here is what it took: 2 subqueries and 2 cross joins with a tally table.  I STILL don't know how to limit the number of subquery results but this solution makes it work so much faster now that the need to reduce is greatly diminished. (`limit` is still not applicable.)

First I learned about CROSS JOINs with tally tables, thanks to my brother.  With that I was able to come up with this crazy solution.  If anyone knows of a better way after reviewing my solution, please do post:

```
SELECT us.name, gs.idGame, suggestion, count(suggestion)
FROM (
    SELECT u.idGame, u.name, SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(u.name, ' ', n.n), ' ', -1) AS user_substr
    FROM usergames u
    CROSS JOIN (
        SELECT N FROM _tally
    ) n
    WHERE u.idGame IS NULL
    AND n.n <= 1 + (LENGTH(u.name) - LENGTH(REPLACE(u.name, ' ', '')))
    HAVING LENGTH(user_substr) > 1
) us, 
(
    SELECT idGame, g.name suggestion, SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(g.name, ' ', n.n), ' ', -1) AS game_substr
    FROM games g
    CROSS JOIN (
        SELECT N FROM _tally
    ) n
    WHERE n.n <= 1 + (LENGTH(g.name) - LENGTH(REPLACE(g.name, ' ', '')))
    HAVING LENGTH(game_substr) > 1
) gs
WHERE user_substr NOT IN (
    SELECT piece from _piecesrestricted   
)
AND game_substr NOT IN (
    SELECT piece from _piecesrestricted   
)
AND (
    LENGTH(user_substr)>3 OR
    user_substr = suggestion
)
AND user_substr = game_substr
GROUP BY suggestion, us.name
ORDER BY us.name ASC, count(suggestion) DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

If you check the documentation [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html), you will see there is a clause:

```
LIMIT <number of records>
```

Unless I misunderstood your question, this is the solution.

Comment: This will limit the total number of results but will not limit the results coming from each individual pairing from the `LIKE` (which can result in a variable number of entries).  I've added a note to specify that `LIMIT` is not what I'm after exactly.

Comment: I see... You want to limit one of the sub-queries only... Hummm... I don't know if that is possible at all. Intuitively, I would say "NO, you cannot do that", but you better check my answer. I might be wrong.

Comment: Thanks, hopefully we will find out